# Comparing a subset of properties between objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a pretty naive way to compare a subset of two objects’ properties with each other. It gets hard to read when there are many properties in the subset. What could be some alternatives?

```
const obj1 = {a: 22, b: 33, c: 44};
const obj2 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44};

JSON.stringify([obj1.a, obj1.b]) === JSON.stringify([obj2.a, obj2.b])
```

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: @Ele I see. Any suggestions how/where to get help finding out alternatives to my code?

Comment: @Ele: This kind of question is pretty standard for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ryan just wait for a while, and you're going to see a lot of alternatives/opinions. There are two so far.

Comment: @Ele: Okay? “A lot of alternatives” is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Subset comparison** : `SubsetCompare` function does a flat comparison of a subset of two objects.

```js
let obj1 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44};
let obj2 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 10};

let subsetCompare = (obj1, obj2, keys) =>  keys.every(key =>  obj1[key] === obj2[key]);

console.log(subsetCompare(obj1, obj2, ['a', 'b']));

console.log(subsetCompare(obj1, obj2, ['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

**Flat comparison** :
`flatCompare` function only compares value of primitive type members and reference of reference type members.

```js
let x = { a : 10};
let y = { a : 10};
let obj1 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44, d:y};
let obj2 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44, d:x};

let flatCompare = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let keys = [];
  if((keys = getKeys(obj1)).length != getKeys(obj2).length)
    return false;
  return keys.every(key => obj1[key] === obj2[key]);
}

let isObject = (obj) => obj === Object(obj);

let getKeys = (obj) => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

console.log(flatCompare(obj1, obj2));
```

**Deep comparison** : `deepCompare` function recursively compares also values of primitive type members of nested objects.

```js
let x = { a : 10};
let y = { a : 10};
let obj1 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44, d:y};
let obj2 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44, d:x};


let deepCompare = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let keys = [];
  if((keys = getKeys(obj1)).length != getKeys(obj2).length)
    return false;
  return keys.every(key => {
    if(isObject(obj1[key]) && isObject(obj2[key]))
      return deepCompare(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    return obj1[key] === obj2[key];
  });
};

let isObject = (obj) => obj === Object(obj);

let getKeys = (obj) => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

console.log(deepCompare(obj1, obj2))
```

Comment: What happens with the nested objects?

Comment: Did you mean `every` instead of `forEach` and `obj1[key]` instead of `obj1.key` and to return a value?

Comment: @Ryan you got sharp eyes

Comment: Since it’s ES6, you can use an arrow function `.every(key => obj1[key] === obj2[key])` (not that you have to)

Comment: @Ele Added both deep and flat comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a function?

```js
let obj1 = {a: 22, b: 33, c: 44};
let obj2 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44};
console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, [`a`, `b`])); // false
console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, [`a`, `c`])); // true
console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, [`b`, `c`])); // false

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2, keys) {
    let i;
    for (i = keys.length - 1; i > -1 && obj1[keys[i]] === obj2[keys[i]]; i--);
    return i === -1; // if i equals -1 it went through the whole loop and did not fail for the second condition
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.every` will give a negative answer faster and is nice and short.

Comment: @Ryan Not really sure how to use that, but edited my answer with a shorter method that resolves faster, since it doesn't have to check each key, but returns false as soon as it finds different values.

Comment: `return keys.every(key => obj1[key] === obj2[key])`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @revilheart's answer but with @Ryan's `every` suggestion:

```js
let obj1 = {a: 22, b: 33, c: 44};
let obj2 = {a: 22, b: 34, c: 44};
console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, [`a`, `b`])); // false
console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, [`a`, `c`])); // true
console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, [`b`, `c`])); // false

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2, keys) {
  return keys.every(key => obj1[key] === obj2[key])
}
```